# How to benchmark speed of data transfer through sockets?

Tags: virtualization, benchmarks

I am trying to send data between a virtual machine and its host using TCP socket and [virtio-serial](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/VirtioSerial). I would like to benchmark these two methods.

Are there any tools available to benchmark this? If not, what is the most efficient and accurate way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `iperf` to benchmark the speed of data transfer between the socket on the host and that on the guest. To use iperf for benchmarking the rate of data transfer using virtIO-serial channel, I am doing the following:

- Boot the VM to create a TCP socket on the host and have created a socket on the guest over virtIO-serial's character device on the guest.
- On the guest, I setup the socket to listen for connections and start iperf using

  ```
  iperf -c localhost -p <port_no>
  ```
- And on the host, I use

  ```
  nc localhost <port_no> > /dev/null
  ```

just to redirect the data I get from the guest to `/dev/null`, since I don't need the benchmarking data.